# Swift: Remove a UIButton attributedTitle

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

If a UIButton has both a title and an attributedTitle set, the attributedTitle is the one that shows.

If I set a button to an attributed title:

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(myAttribText, for: .normal)
```

and later in the app I want to set the button to a regular title:

```
myButton.setTitle(myRegularText, for: .normal)
```

Is there a line of code I can use to remove the attributedTitle on the button so that it will not override the new title I have set for the button? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `myButton.setAttributedTitle(nil, for: .normal)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the AttributedTitle to `nil` before setting using `setTitle` for your button, Its working i have checked it.

like this

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(nil, for: .normal)
myButton.setTitle(myRegularText, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the underline attribute, you should to set the AttributedTitle by this method like this:

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: myRegularText, attributes: nil), for: .normal)
```